# Changing colour of selected variable in IntelliJ while debugging

Tags: intellij-idea

When I debug code in IntelliJ, and double click a variable its background becomes white and the colour of the font is almost white too. It is perhaps due to my customised scheme. I looked at Settings->Editor->Color scheme for appropriate setting to change the colour but I cannot find one. Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the ***Foreground*** attribute for Java | Variables | ***Local variable*** in Color Scheme settings. Note that when you select the corresponding symbol in the code snippet sample in Colors & Fonts settings, IDE navigates you to corresponding symbol type node:
[image]

IDE will also navigate you to corresponding node right from the Editor if you select *Jump to Colors and Fonts* action (Help | Find Action, type *Jump to Colors...*):
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but it seems that this is not the correct setting. I've changed the value you describe but I still have almost white variable. Please have a look at [my screenshot](http://storage4.static.itmages.com/i/18/0410/h_1523375917_6795613_264acaddfb.png)